# Injecting the Java Static method into kotlin class via constructor injection

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

**I have a static function defined in java class**

```
public class CommonUtils {

   public static void extractZipFile(File zipFile) {
        // --- > Our static method
   }

}
```

**I am trying to inject the above static method in the kotlin class below as constructor injection**

```
class DownloadAssets @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext var context: Context
) : Download {
        // --- > Our kotlin class where we need to inject in constructor
}
```

**Questions:**

1. How to perform this injection using `Hilt-DI`
2. What is the correct way to achieve this
3. Is this possible

Comment: I'm not sure on the correct method to do this, but it is possible with "private val function: KFunction1<File, Unit> = CommonUtils::extractZipFile" in the constructor. Then you can add @ Named annotation and provide a @Provides for the named parameter

Comment: Do you really need an instance of CommonUtils injected, since its a util class and methods are static, so they can be called from anywhere?